# How to forward SMS messages from one phone to a different one via PHP or Java

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

I would like to set up an my application to work in a way that I could have all messages to my phone, +254 710 ***** , forwarded to a URL, where there's some PHP/ Java code that in turn forwads the message to another different phone, +254 722  *****. Is this possible? How can I go about it?

So far I've been looking at SMS gateway providers, but I just can't seem to find such a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: 
yes, it's possible.

Long answer: 
Not clear enough what reason is doing it.
In general you are right with looking at SMS providers. Different providers have different API and need different solutions. So there is no universal solution for you. 
But the most likely you could just tune your phone to forward SMSes.